# Multiple paired samples t-tests?

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, paired-comparisons

I'm trying to determine the effect of taking a training course on various aspects of being a good quality worker. I have pre-test and post-test data on 7 different ways job performance can be viewed. I'm currently performing 7 different paired samples t-tests on the data, to see the effect on each individual aspect. Is there a test to calculate the overall effect on job performance (by comparing all 7 aspects at once)? I'm trying to use SPSS but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Did abhinavkulkarni answer your question?  If so, please mark that answer as accepted.  Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first spell out what amounts to "overall improvement". If "overall improvement" means improvement in **each** of the aspects then your test is essentially **AND** of individual tests. i.e.

Suppose your model is:

$
improvement = \beta_0 + \beta_1\cdot x_1 + ... + \beta_7\cdot x_7 + training*(\delta_0 + \delta_1\cdot x_1 + ... + \delta_7\cdot x_7)
$

where $training$ is a binary indicator whether training was received or not. The parameters of this model are $\vec{\theta} = (\beta_0, ..., \beta_7, \delta_0, ..., \delta_7)^T$. Say $\vec{\theta}_\delta = (\delta_0, ..., \delta_7)^T$

Then as you mentioned you can individually test for:

$H_0: \delta_i\ vs\ H_a: \delta_i <= 0, \forall i \in (1, 7)$.

However if you wish to test for all of them simultaneously, then you are essentially testing for:

$H_0: \vec{\theta}_\delta > \vec{0}\ vs\ H_a: \vec{\theta}_\delta <= 0$

Now, you can easily find the estimates $\vec{\hat{\theta}_\delta}$ of $\vec{\theta}_\delta$ and $\hat{\sigma}\{\vec{\theta}_\delta\}$.

Also,

$\frac{\vec{\hat{\theta}_\delta} - \vec{\theta}_\delta}{\hat{\sigma}\{\vec{\theta}_\delta\}} \sim t_{df}$ and $\frac{\vec{\hat{\theta}_\delta}}{\hat{\sigma}\{\vec{\theta}_\delta\}} \stackrel{H_0}{\sim} t_{df}$

Thus, all you need is a simple one-sided t-test.