# Are multiple paired t-tests among 2 groups safe and effective?

Tags: t-test, paired-comparisons, paired-data

**Part A**:
Suppose I have 2 groups (pre-treatment, post-treatment) and for each subject I record 3 variables. So my rows look like:

```
      pre             post
var1 var2 var3 | var1 var2 var3
```

I'd like to examine whether the treatment affects var1, var2 and var3. Can I simply do 3 paired t-tests ? Like: paired-t-test(var1-pre, var1-post), paired-t-test(var2-pre, var2-post), etc. Or is there some more appropriate test ?

**Part B**: Suppose that I also have a categorical variable like:

```
      pre             post
cat var1 var2 var3 | cat var1 var2 var3
```

(ofcourse since the subject is the same in each row 'cat' has the same value in two columns). What would be the most appropriate test in this case ?

Relevant question: [Multiple paired samples t-tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44866/multiple-paired-samples-t-tests)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why a paired t-test would be unsuitable, unless your data is not normally distributed. Your initial track of 3 paired t-tests seems right.
For categorical paired tests, you can use the Mcnemar test. Should work in your case.